# OutputCache not working in MVC 4, where should I put it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache

I'm trying to attain a web MVC program that edits a certain employee. When I click the edit button, then edit some info of the employee. I want the edited employee NOT TO BE EDITED AFTER 5 sec. That's why I'm trying to use **[OutputCache(Duration = 5)]**  But I don't know where to put it. I've tried putting it in all methods. But nothing is working. Thanks!

```
 public class EmployeeController : Controller
{

    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        return new List<Employee>
{

    new Employee{
        ID = 1,
        Name = "Allan",
        JoiningDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
        Age = 23
    },
    new Employee{
        ID = 2,
        Name = "Carson",
        JoiningDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
        Age = 45
    },
    new Employee{
        ID = 3,
        Name = "Carson",
        JoiningDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
        Age = 37
    },
    new Employee{
        ID = 4,
        Name = "Laura",
        JoiningDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
        Age = 26
    },
};
    }


    public static List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>
{
new Employee{
    ID = 1,
    Name = "Allan",
    JoiningDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
    Age = 23
},
new Employee{
    ID = 2,
    Name = "Carson",
    JoiningDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
    Age = 45
},
new Employee{
    ID = 3,
    Name = "Carson",
    JoiningDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
    Age = 37
},
new Employee{
    ID = 4,
    Name = "Laura",
    JoiningDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
    Age = 26
},
    };



    // GET: Employee
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employees = from e in empList 
                orderby e.ID 
                select e; 
return View(employees); 
    }

    // GET: Employee/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Employee/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Employee/Create

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Create(Employee emp)
    {
        try
        {

            empList.Add(emp);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }


    // GET: Employee/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        List<Employee> empList = GetEmployeeList();
        var employee = empList.Single(m => m.ID == id);
        return View(employee);


}


// POST: Employee/Edit/5

[HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            var employee = empList.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            if (TryUpdateModel(employee))
            {
                //To Do:- database code 
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(employee);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    // GET: Employee/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Employee/Delete/5

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: OutputCache has nothing to do with whether or not an entity could be edited. If anything, you're just caching the initial state of the form, such that it would not initially show the updated information from the last edit. In short, what you're doing here makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: To prevent additional edits for some time period, you would have to timestamp the entity in the database (for example, you could add a DateTime property like `LastModifiedDate`). Then, you would have to check that when someone attempts to post an edit and disregard the edit if it's been less than the timeframe you pick. However, 5 seconds is so insignificant that this is hardly worth it. By the time the user could load the edit page, make some edits and submit, 5 seconds has likely already passed anyways.